How do I disable kendo-editor-insert-table-button, kendo-toolbar-button in kendo-editor
I use kendo-editor for my project. However, I want to disable some button such as: kendo-toolbar-button, kendo-editor-insert-table-button, ... depend on defined business logic.
I tried adding [disable]="true" in html but it's unsuccessfull. Please let me know how I can disable them. Many thanks
adding [disable]="true" in html but it's unsuccessfull
